# What is this "of" here?

Tags: grammar

> “I believe there are more instances of the abridgement of the freedom of the people by gradual and silent **encroachments of those in power** than by violent and sudden usurpations.”
>
> — [James Madison, speech at the Virginia Convention to ratify the Federal Constitution (1788)](http://www.constitution.org/rc/rat_va_05.htm)

What is this "of"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *of* is a possessive, but since it describes an action, the encroachments are performed *by* the agent that "possesses" them.

This use of *of* is similar to:

> I watched the movements **of** his eyes.
>   I admired the strong strokes **of** the swimmer.

Here, the eyes are making the movements, so the movements "belong" to the eyes, they are *their* movements.
Similarly, the strokes are performed *by* the swimmer, so they are *her* strokes.

Comment: Those in power encroach on the freedom?

Comment: Yes, that is what Madison is saying. His point was made to warn law-makers that many laws, instead of _giving_ freedom, _take away_ freedom, and that _that_ process is the main reason why people are often not free.